# UWP WebView: Playing audio when the window is minimized without a source

Tags: javascript, uwp

So currently I am developing an application that I'd of hoped to work on Windows, Xbox, etc.

I am trying to developer a wrapper for a javascript library that plays music. This library does not exist in any other form, and only provides the music as encrypted files. It handles playing the audio, pausing, fetching, etc. To change anything you call js methods.

So I am currently using a hidden UWP webview, with custom js/html to play and pause the audio coming from the js library. I was fiddling around with it and noticed if I minimized it, the audio is stopped from the webview. I cannot set a media source for a backgroundtask as I cannot get the actual source of the audio. That is all handled by the js library.

I am hoping to find a way to use UWP, along with this webview "hack". Am I trying to accomplish the impossible?

Comment: It's impossible.